# AngularJS Jamine testing that the broadcast message has been send Only once

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I'm trying to test that boradcase message been send only once

```
 expect(rootScope.$broadcast.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
```

The code itself:

```
 $rootScope.$broadcast("page:done_loading");
```

So, test does not work. I'm not sure about the syntax. Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to set up a spy (you are not showing much code so not sure if you have already done so).

For example:

*Jasmine 2.0:* `spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast').and.callThrough();`

*Jasmine 1.3:* `spyOn($rootScope, '$broadcast').andCallThrough();`

Note that `and.callThrough()` not might be the correct behavior for the spy in your situation.

Then to verify it was called once:

*Jasmine 2.0:* `expect($rootScope.$broadcast.calls.count()).toEqual(1);`

*Jasmine 1.3:* `expect($rootScope.$broadcast.callCount).toEqual(1);`

**Demo (Jasmine 2.0)**: http://plnkr.co/edit/4xeZOzxOuYNvvASY8jTM

Comment: that works. Thanks. Although would be interesting to know how to check if it was invoked N-times with some specific argument - like:expect($rootScope.$broadcast("arg1").callCount).toEqual(1); or expect($rootScope.$broadcast.callCount).toEqual(1).with("arg1);